# php query in loop echo's duplicates

Tags: php, loops, duplicates, echo

Heres a loop that lists all the products purchased (Digital Access Pass) by a user.
I wish to have a Wordpress posts featured image show up beside each product.
However, there is no solid relation between the DAP product and the Wordpress post. So my work around for this is to make sure the DAP product has the same name/title as the WP Post. 
My problem is, using the code I have so far (between the hash tags), it basically runs the queries for each DAP product in the loop and therefore spits out duplicates for X amount of DAP products.

So if theres three DAP products, and two of them have a matching title with WP posts, the result looks like this...

16521652

Hope that makes sense.
Appreciate any assistance.

```
global $wpdb;

//loop over each product from the list
foreach ($userProducts as $userProduct) {
    if($productid != "ALL") {
        $productIdArray = explode(",",$productid);

        //if( $userProduct->getProduct_id() != $productid ) {
        if( !in_array($userProduct->getProduct_id(), $productIdArray) ) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    $product = Dap_Product::loadProduct($userProduct->getProduct_id());

    $expired = false;
    if($user->hasAccessTo($product->getId()) === false) {
        $expired = true;
    }



    //##########################################################################

    /*1.Get post ID by post title if you know the title or the title variable*/

    $postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $product->getName() . "'" );
    $postname = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $product->getName() . "'" );

    if ($product->getName() == $postname):
    echo $postid;
    endif;

    /*2.use get_post($post_id) to get whatever you want to echo*/
    $getpost= get_post($postid);
    $postcontent= $getpost->post_content;
    echo $postcontent;

    //##########################################################################

    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '<br/><br/>';
} //end foreach

return $content;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick workaround would be to store the retrieved post names/ids in an array; to avoid duplicates, before storing each value, check if it already is stored:

```
if (in_array($postid,$values)==false) $values[] = $postid;
```

Then, *after* retrieving all the values (i.e. after the loop), proceed to get the posts and post their contents.

**EDIT:**

> Would you mind telling me how to store the values in an array?

*Before* the loop, initialize the array:

```
$values = array();
```

After retrieving `$postid` and `$postname`, and checking that the product's name equals the post name, put the value in the array:

```
if (in_array($postid,$values)==false) $values[] = $postid;
```

*After the loop* ends, you will have the ID's of the posts you were looking for. Iterate the `$values` array using another `foreach` loop and use them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Would you mind telling me how to store the values in an array? I don't really know how to work with arrays. How would I use that line my code?

Comment: Getting this error...

Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument

Comment: I can't seem to work out how to store the values from the select query into $values as an array. People always seem to use a while loop to do this but in this case, I need to query to work with the while loop its already in.